# Derive the error formula

Tags: newton-raphson

I know that Newton's method is $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$ for n $\geq$ 0. Now, if I consider an interval [a, b] and I suppose that there exists a root $\alpha \in (a, b)(f{(\alpha)} = 0)$. I also assume that both f' and f'' are continuous functions and f'($\alpha$) $\neq$ 0. Using Taylor's Theorem, we have that for some $c_n$ between $\alpha$ and $x_n$ that:

f($\alpha$) = f($x_n$) + ($\alpha-x_n$)f'($x_n$) + $\frac{(\alpha - x_n)^2}{2}f''(c_n)$.

0 = f($x_n$) + ($\alpha-x_n$)f'($x_n$)$ + \frac{(\alpha - x_n)^2}{2}f''(c_n)$.

If we divide both sides of the equation by f'($x_n$), we get that:

0 = $\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$+ ($\alpha-x_n$) + $\frac{(\alpha - x_n)^2}{2}\frac{f''(c_n)}{f'(x_n)}$.

Since $x_{n+1}$ = $x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$, then, by rearranging these terms, we get $\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$ = $x_n - x_{n+1}$. We can substitute this in the equation above and solve for $\alpha - x_{n+1}$. We get: 0 = ($x_n- x_{n+1}$) + ($\alpha-x_n$) + $\frac{(\alpha - x_n)^2}{2}\frac{f''(c_n)}{f'(x_n)}$.

So, $\alpha-x_{n+1}$ = -$\frac{(\alpha - x_n)^2}{2}\frac{f''(c_n)}{f'(x_n)}$.

So I have a function f(x) = $x^2$ - a. I know that the first derivative of this fuction is 2x. If I substitute this into the above equation, I'd get this, $\alpha-x_{n+1}$ = -$\frac{(\alpha - x_n)^2}{2}\frac{f''(c_n)}{2x}$. Now I get this:

$\alpha-x_{n+1}$ = -$\frac{(\alpha - x_n)^2}{2x}f''(c_n)$

How do I go from this to this final equation:

$\sqrt{a}-x_{n+1} = \frac{-1}{2x_n}(\sqrt{a}-x_{n})^2$

Comment: I don't know, but I think your next-to-last displayed equation should be $$\alpha-x_{n+1}=-(\alpha-x_n)^2/(2x_n)$$

Comment: Where did you get $2x_n$ from? Because the second derivative of $f(x_n)$ is 2? What does that have to do with f’’($c_n$)? @GerryMyerson

Comment: $f(x)=x^2-a$, so $f''(x)=2$ for all $x$, so, in particular, $f''(c_n)=2$, no matter what $c_n$ is. In your third-from-last display, you have a term, $f'(x_n)$. That evaluates to $2x_n$, but instead you've written it as $2x$.

Comment: Okay, thank you @GerryMyerson